# Can't get browserify to use babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to use [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) in my project and I am attempting to use class properties. However, when I run through browserify (with [Laravel's Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#babel)). I get the error `Missing class properties transform. while parsing file`. Is there something I'm missing to get class properties to work with browserify?

```
Browserify Failed!: /Users/.../resources/assets/js/pages/Show/CampaignStore.js: Missing class properties transform. while parsing file: /Users/.../resources/assets/js/pages/Show/CampaignStore.js
 Missing class properties transform.
  2 |
  3 | class CampaignStore {
> 4 |   id = Math.random();
    |   ^
  5 |   @observable title = '';
  6 |   @observable messages = [];
  7 |
```

My .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

The class

```
import { observable, computed } from 'mobx';

class CampaignStore {
  id = Math.random();
  @observable title = '';
  @observable messages = [];

  // ...
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var HOST = process.env.SERVER || 'http://localhost';

elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'babelify',
    options: {
        presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
    }
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('pages/Show.js', 'public/js/bundles/show.js');

    mix.sass('clean.scss');

    mix.browserSync({
        proxy: HOST
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you check which one of the babel configs is actually picked up? .babelrc or the one in the gulp file? You might need to update the gulp file to use stage-0 instead of stage-1 and transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried just the .babelrc file, then just the options in the gulp file, then both but nothing works (I also attempted to switch the gulpfile to stage-0). I just switched things over to webpack and without any changes to the .babelrc file everything works. I'll keep this open just in case someone is able to produce an answer for others to read.

Comment: @csm232s Were you able to solve the problem? I'm running the same setup as you do (laravel-elixir with browserify) and can't get rid of the Missing class properties transform error even though I included the "transform-class-properties" as a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You should override exactly `babelify` transformer:

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers
  .find(transformer => transformer.name === 'babelify')
  .options = {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1'],
    plugins: ['transform-class-properties'],
  };
```

or just use the same babel config file:

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers
  .find(transformer => transformer.name === 'babelify')
  .options = require('./package.json').babel;
```